# How to Create an Index in MYSQL for two tables

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

I have two tables.  The first has the `City`, `State` and `Zip` of rental properties as entered by users of the website.  Some of the city names are misspelled. The second table has almost every (but not all) `Cities`, `States` and `Zip codes` of cities in the US from the US Postal Service.

I am trying to run the following SQL statement to update the rental property table records with the correct name as provided by the US Postal service. but only for records with a specific "Payment_Plan".  I will re-use this statement for about 15 different "Payment_Plan" types.  So the only thing that will change will be the value given in "Payment_Plan":

```
UPDATE tblRentals 
LEFT JOIN tblZip 
  ON tblRentals.List_Zip = tblZip.Zip 
  AND tblRentals.Payment_Plan = 'LINX' 
SET tblRentals.List_City = tblZip.City;
```

I am using a LEFT Join because not every zip code is in my version of the US Postal table as it is a few years old.

That SQL statement takes 15 seconds to update only 200 records.  I am guessing it is because I need some sort of index between the two tables. There are 125,000 records in tblRentals and about 45,000 records in tblZip.

I really do not know a whole lot about indexes, but what would be the correct SQL syntax to create an index that would speedup this up?

Comment: Can you post your table structure? Which indexes exists right now? You probably need indexes on `tblRentals.List_Zip` and `tblZip.Zip`

Comment: `tblZip` has an index on `zip`. `tblRentals` has an index on `Payment_Plan`, `List_City`. It doesn't have one on `List_Zip`.

Comment: OK. To speed up the JOIN you also need an index on `tblRentals.List_Zip`. Also - I am not sure you really want a `LEFT JOIN` here. What do you want to get for zip codes that do not exist in  `tblZip`? With `LEFT JOIN` you will get NULL for `tblRentals.List_City` for such zip codes... If you use a `JOIN`, an index on `tblRentals.Payment_Plan` will help a lot as well.

Comment: I wasn't too sure about the `LEFT JOIN`.  I thought it would not return any results if `tblZip` did not have a zip code that `tblRentals` did.  I'll change that back to `INNER JOIN` and see what it does.  How do I go about creating an index on `tblRentals.List_Zip`?  Is it just: `CREATE INDEX tblRentals_List_Zip
ON tblRentals (List_Zip);`

Comment: Please read the manual - it's simple and clear: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

Comment: When there is not a result in tblZip for a zip code, I want it to leave the current city name as is in tblRentals.  Would that be an `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: Adding the index sped it up to 7 seconds from 15 seconds. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting from comments to answer so this question can be closed:

Add an index on `tblRentals.List_Zip`.

And yes - if you want records that have a zip code in tblRentals but no match in tblZip to be left untouched, use `INNER JOIN` rather than `LEFT JOIN`.